# Listview click is not working for navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a xml layout for navigation drawer as follows,

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Im setting onItemClickLister as follows,

```
mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"sd",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

But still the onItemClickListener for navigation drawer is not getting fired.

Comment: still the same problem persists

Comment: im following this example https://trinitytuts.com/navigation-drawer-with-tabview-in-android/

Comment: android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants  to  your drawer_item.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying removing [`android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants`"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:descendantFocusability). Because of this property, `ListView` will get focus only if none of its descendants want it. Also remove, [`android:focusable="false`"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:focusable) to make `ListView` focusable.

Make drawer's `ListView` the second and last element of `DrawerLayout`. [Demo](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#DrawerLayout) from developer docs.

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: still the same problem persists

Comment: im following this example trinitytuts.com/navigation-drawer-with-tabview-in-android

Comment: @Stanly post your activity

Answer (score 0):

i know it may against your question but i suggest you to use navigationdrawer with **support designs**. there you can add navigation item and can add headerview also.

it will have default padding as per android design guideline.

here is complete [tutorial](http://androidessence.com/creating-a-material-design-navigation-drawer/)